# ¿Cómo puedo descargar un archivo subido de una carpeta con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Esta es la tabla de archivos donde lo pongo para descargar

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM formulario ";
$sqli = mysqli_query($enlace,$consulta );

while($tak= mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){

?>

<table>

<tr class="tr1">

<td class="td1">Titulo</td>
<td class="td1" >Archivo</td>
<td class="td1">Usuario</td>
<td class="td1">Descripcion</td>
<td class="td1" >Tipo</td>
<td class="td1" >Fecha</td>
<td class="td1">Tamaño</td>
<td class="td1" >Sistema</td>
<td class="td1" >Descargas</td>


</tr>



<tr>

<td><?php echo $tak['titulo']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['archivo']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['usuario']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['descripcion']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['tipo']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['fecha']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['tamaño']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['sistema']?></td>
<td><?php echo $tak['descargas']?></td>
<td><a href=" subidos/ <?php echo $tak['archivo'] ?>" download="<?php echo $tak['archivo'] ?>">Descargar</a></td>


</tr>
```

Este es el código de descarga; se descarga pero me dice archivo no encontrado. `Subidos/` es la carpeta donde se almacenan mis archivos subidos.

```
<td><a href=" subidos/ <?php echo $tak['archivo'] ?>" download="<?php echo $tak['archivo'] ?>">Descargar</a></td>
```

`$tak ['archivo']` en la tabla donde está el nombre del archivo y este es el error que me aparece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A tu variable **$tak['archivo']** si le estás asignando algo?, comparte esa parte del código donde le asignas un valor.

Comment: $archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

Comment: $tak['archivo'] es de la tabla dondo almaceno los archivos

Comment: Gracias Luis pero sería de más ayuda que edites tu pregunta y compartas toda esa parte del código para verlo completo.

Comment: Cuando guardas el nombre del archivo en la bd, tambien guardas su extension? ademas, el archivo donde tienes ese codigo para descargar se encuentra segun la direccion que indicas? es decir, fuera de subidos/?

Comment: Ademas indicas que se descarga, que estas descargando? dices que te muestra que el archivo no se encontro, donde te muestra eso si el archivo si se descargo?

Comment: Otra cosa, tu carpeta es Subidos/ o subidos/? los links son sensibles a las mayusculas

Comment: ernesto si la extension tambien se guarda, solo se encuentra en subidos/ los archivos, se descarga pero me dice que no se encontro el archivo

Comment: aiudaa............

Comment: Te sobran espacios `href=" subidos/ <?php echo $tak['archivo'] ?>"`, debería ser: `href="subidos/<?php echo $tak['archivo'] ?>"`

Comment: GRACIAASS TRIBY